# Java: Some form elements are partially covered by others

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I designed a form for showing a graph and table inside a frame. Here is the code:

```
package ExaData;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;


public class ShowGraph extends javax.swing.JFrame {


String[][] data;
String[] columns={"Tanım","Değer"};

 Sessionn obj;
  String SGA="SGA";
  String PGA="PGA";
  String JAVAPOOL="JAVAPOOL";
   JCheckBox SGA_CHECK;
    JCheckBox PGA_CHECK;
    JCheckBox JAVA_POOL_CHECK;
     JTable table;
     JPanel btnPanel,tblPanel;
    ChartPanel CP;
     JFreeChart chart;
     DefaultCategoryDataset dataset;
    boolean sgaflag=true;
    boolean pgaflag=true;
    boolean javapoolflag=true;
    JScrollPane scroller;
     JTableHeader header ;
 JCheckBox[] checkboxes;
 boolean[] chkboxflag;
  public ShowGraph()
  {

   //   super();

      SGA_CHECK=new JCheckBox("SGA");
         PGA_CHECK=new JCheckBox("PGA");
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK=new JCheckBox("JAVA POOL");
         SGA_CHECK.setSelected(true);
         PGA_CHECK.setSelected(true);
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK.setSelected(true);
           btnPanel= new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
           tblPanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(SGA_CHECK);
        btnPanel.add(PGA_CHECK);
        btnPanel.add(JAVA_POOL_CHECK);
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(tblPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 


            PGA_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {                   
                pgaflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
              update();
            }
        });
        SGA_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                 sgaflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
              update();
            }
        });
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                 javapoolflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
               update();
            }
        });

  }


     private CategoryDataset createDataset() {

        dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();


        if(sgaflag){
        dataset.addValue(32.4, SGA, "Node 1");
          dataset.addValue(43.2, SGA, "Node 2");
          dataset.addValue(23.0, SGA, "Node 3");
            dataset.addValue(13.0, SGA, "Node 4");
        }
            if(pgaflag){
        dataset.addValue(17.8, PGA, "Node 1");
          dataset.addValue(15.6, PGA, "Node 2");
           dataset.addValue(111.3, PGA, "Node 3");
           dataset.addValue(11.8, PGA, "Node 4");
            }
            if(javapoolflag){
        dataset.addValue(27.7, JAVAPOOL, "Node 1");   
        dataset.addValue(18.3, JAVAPOOL, "Node 2");      
        dataset.addValue(25.5, JAVAPOOL, "Node 3");      
        dataset.addValue(29.5, JAVAPOOL, "Node 4");
            }
        return dataset;
    }
 private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {

         chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
            "EXADATA Görünümü",  // chart title
            "Node'lar",                  // domain axis label
            "Yüzde Dağılım",                     // range axis label
            dataset,                     // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,    // the plot orientation
            true,                        // legend
            true,                        // tooltips
            false                        // urls
        );
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();


        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
        StackedBarRenderer renderer = (StackedBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setRenderAsPercentages(true);
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
        new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
        return chart;

    }

public void veriCek(String[][] data)
    {
    this.data=data;
    }

 public void run()
{  

       chart = createChart(createDataset());
      table =new JTable(data,columns);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
       table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
       table.setEnabled(false);
   CP=new ChartPanel(chart);
    scroller = new JScrollPane(table); 
           this.add(CP, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
           tblPanel.add(scroller,BorderLayout.SOUTH);         
         this.setSize(600,600);

    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(this);     
    this.setVisible(true);

}
 public void update()
 {
 this.remove(CP);
       chart = createChart(createDataset());
   CP=new ChartPanel(chart);  
           this.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
 }


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i run this, my table is overlapping the graph. How can i solve that?

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT**: I replaced chart with a simple image. It overlays the checkbox panel, also it causes some glitches when i try to resize the window. Here is my edited code:

```
package ExaData;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StackedBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;


public class ShowGraph extends javax.swing.JFrame {


String[][] data;
String[] columns={"Tanım","Değer"};

 Sessionn obj;
  String SGA="SGA";
  String PGA="PGA";
  String JAVAPOOL="JAVAPOOL";
   JCheckBox SGA_CHECK;
    JCheckBox PGA_CHECK;
    JCheckBox JAVA_POOL_CHECK;
     JTable table;
     JPanel btnPanel,tblPanel,cPanel;
    ChartPanel CP;
     JFreeChart chart;
     DefaultCategoryDataset dataset;
    boolean sgaflag=true;
    boolean pgaflag=true;
    boolean javapoolflag=true;
    JScrollPane scroller;
     JTableHeader header ;
 JCheckBox[] checkboxes;
 boolean[] chkboxflag;
  public ShowGraph()
  {

   //   super();

      SGA_CHECK=new JCheckBox("SGA");
         PGA_CHECK=new JCheckBox("PGA");
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK=new JCheckBox("JAVA POOL");
         SGA_CHECK.setSelected(true);
         PGA_CHECK.setSelected(true);
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK.setSelected(true);
           btnPanel= new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
         tblPanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
          cPanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(SGA_CHECK);
        btnPanel.add(PGA_CHECK);
        btnPanel.add(JAVA_POOL_CHECK);
       this.add(cPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     this.add(tblPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 


            PGA_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {                   
                pgaflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
              update();
            }
        });
        SGA_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                 sgaflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
              update();
            }
        });
         JAVA_POOL_CHECK.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                 javapoolflag=e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
               update();
            }
        });

  }


     private CategoryDataset createDataset() {

        dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        //BURADA ANA TANIMLAMA BİTTİ


        if(sgaflag){
        dataset.addValue(32.4, SGA, "Node 1");
          dataset.addValue(43.2, SGA, "Node 2");
          dataset.addValue(23.0, SGA, "Node 3");
            dataset.addValue(13.0, SGA, "Node 4");
        }
            if(pgaflag){
        dataset.addValue(17.8, PGA, "Node 1");
          dataset.addValue(15.6, PGA, "Node 2");
           dataset.addValue(111.3, PGA, "Node 3");
           dataset.addValue(11.8, PGA, "Node 4");
            }
            if(javapoolflag){
        dataset.addValue(27.7, JAVAPOOL, "Node 1");   
        dataset.addValue(18.3, JAVAPOOL, "Node 2");      
        dataset.addValue(25.5, JAVAPOOL, "Node 3");      
        dataset.addValue(29.5, JAVAPOOL, "Node 4");
            }
        return dataset;
    }
 private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {

         chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
            "EXADATA Görünümü",  // chart title
            "Node'lar",                  // domain axis label
            "Yüzde Dağılım",                     // range axis label
            dataset,                     // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,    // the plot orientation
            true,                        // legend
            true,                        // tooltips
            false                        // urls
        );
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();


        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
        StackedBarRenderer renderer = (StackedBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setRenderAsPercentages(true);
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
        new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
        return chart;

    }

public void veriCek(String[][] data)
    {
    this.data=data;
    }

 public void run()
{  

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400,300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 400);
    g.dispose();
      JLabel l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    cPanel.add(l);
       chart = createChart(createDataset());
    table =new JTable(data,columns);
   table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
     table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
     table.setEnabled(false);
 //  CP=new ChartPanel(chart);

  //     this.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    scroller = new JScrollPane(table); 
         tblPanel.add(scroller,BorderLayout.SOUTH);         
      //   this.setSize(600,600);
         this.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(this);     
    this.setVisible(true);

}
 public void update()
 {
 this.remove(CP);
       chart = createChart(createDataset());
   CP=new ChartPanel(chart); 
           this.add(CP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
 }


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: A suggestion. When posting code examples, especially runnable ones, avoid using code from third party APIs, as some users may not have access to them. In this case, you could have easily replaced the chart with a JPanel, and I'm sure the same `JPanel` would get covered up also

Comment: I can't compile that due to the JFreeChart dependency, but `this.setSize(600,600);` looks suspicious.  It should be `this.pack()`..

Comment: Also from the comment in your last post, I told you not to set the size of the frame, and just `pack()` it. You have failed to do so.

Comment: @peeskillet  I did not notice the comment last thread, but ..great minds think alike.  ;)

Comment: @peeskillet i tried it, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: *"it doesn't solve my problem."* Use it anyway!  It is bound to cause problems to explicitly set the frame size.

Comment: It may not solve your problem, but setting the size is making it worse. The JScrollPane has a preffered size set. So by you setting the size of the frame, it limits space for other components.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for suggestion. Anyway, this problem doesn't seem to be solved.

Comment: Do what I said and replace _all_ third party API code (JFreeChart) with standard API code (JPanel). Make it compilable for us and I'm sure we can solve your problem. This doesn't seem like a big problem that can't be fixed, but no one can compile your code, so we can't test.

Comment: What do you mean by replacing? I need to draw this graph. How i'm supposed to draw it without JfreeChart?

Comment: *"How i'm supposed to draw it without JfreeChart?"*  Don't draw the graph.  Simply replace it with an image in a `JLabel`.  Getting an image is as simple as `BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(400,300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`..

Comment: I mean [**create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without third party code. If you need to write up a whole other simplified program that replicates your problem, then do it. Otherwise we can't help you. We can only throw guesses that may make your situation worse

Comment: Why are all the `org.jfree..` imports still there?  Those imports cause compilation errors, and we cannot run the code.  Please put more effort into actually *reading* the MCTaRE document carefully, and following the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an answer. Just a suggestion that is too long for a comment**

Another suggestion, since I think this question may be connected to our discussion yesterday where you're trying to add dynamic components to your frame - instead don't do this. The `GroupLayout` that GUI Builder provides as default makes it difficult to dynamically add component. Just create a `JDialog` form that already has all the components in place, and just pass data to it through its constructor. The data should be the data required to formulate your table and chart. Something like this

```
public class ChartTableDialog extends JDialog {
    private int[][] data;

    public ChartTableDialog(final JFrame frame, boolean modal, int[][] data) {
        super(frame, model);
        this.data = data;
    }

    // somewhere else in the code you will use data[][] for formulate
    // your chart and your table
}
```

Then in your main `JFrame` form, say a button triggers the `JDialog` to pop up, gather the data, then pass it to the `JDilaog`. Something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int[][] data = getSomeData();

    new ChartTableDialog(this, true, data);
}
```

That would be the simplest way to do it.

Another would be to use a `CardLayout` but I would have to go through a whole tutorial with you on how to do this with GUI Builder, as its somewhat complex. So I would suggest the first option for now.

Comment: Not sure what's different about your edit beside the fact that now that space where the chart was _isn't_ covered up. Your code is still not compilable for us. Keep in mind, not everyone has `JFreeChart`. Also when making up your `JDialog` I'd suggest layout the table and chart out horizontally. That long vertical look just looks plain weird.

Comment: No but it's only suggestion here. I guess you're telling the solution but i haven't got enought time and i'm not ine good mood so thanks for your efforts.